# SCOPE_IDENTITY() id's conflicts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 3 tables `UniversityReg`, `SupporterReg` & `Login`. If university or supporter register with the system, always general details goes to their table & login details goes to `Login` table. In here I use `scope_identity`.

I'm getting error when I go to save supporter reg details.

Errors

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SupporterReg_SP, Line 16
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SupporterId', table 'CounsellingDB.dbo.SupporterReg'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>
> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SupporterReg_SP, Line 20
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'LoginID', table 'CounsellingDB.dbo.Login'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

UniversityReg SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UniversityReg_SP]
  (
@Username varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@UniversityName varchar(50) ,
@GovernmentRegNo varchar(50) ,
@Country varchar(50) ,
@CreatedBy varchar(50)

    )
AS
DECLARE @LoginID int
INSERT INTO UniversityReg   (UniversityName,GovernmentRegNo,Country,CreatedBy,ShortCode)values(@UniversityName,@GovernmentRegNo,@Country,@CreatedBy,'UNI')

SET @LoginID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO Login values(@LoginID,@Username,@Password,'UNI')

RETURN
```

SupporterReg_SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SupporterReg_SP]
   (
@UserName varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@SupporterName varchar(50),
@University varchar(50) ,
@ContactNo varchar(50),
@Email varchar(50),
@StudentLocation varchar(50) 


       )

          AS
       DECLARE @LoginID int
        INSERT INTO   SupporterReg(SupporterName,University,ContactNo,Email,StudentLocation,ImagePath,ShortCode)V   alues(@SupporterName,@University,@ContactNo,@Email,@StudentLocation,'','SUP')

SET @LoginID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO Login values(@LoginID,@UserName,@Password,'SUP')

RETURN
```

UniversityReg Table

```
[UniversityId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Username] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Password] [varchar](50) NULL,
[UniversityName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[GovernmentRegNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ShortCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
```

Login Table

```
[LoginID] [int] NOT NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Password] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[ShortCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL
```

SupporterReg table

```
[SupporterId] [int] NOT NULL,
[SupporterName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[University] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ContactNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
[StudentLocation] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ImagePath] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ShortCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
```

Comment: has UniversityReg    and SupporterReg an identity column ?

Comment: How are the tables defined? How are they related to each other (what are the foreign keys)?

Comment: do you have `SupporterId` set up as an identity column that auto-increments? Also, I can see a possible primary key conflict in `Login` occurring since you're using identity values from different tables there.

Comment: @Shmiddty yes.how cn i solve it ?

Comment: `[SupporterId] [int] NOT NULL,` is not an identity column. And your design is just simply flawed. There is no way to reference the UniversityReg or SupporterReg tables from the Login table, why are you using their identities to populate the login table?

Comment: @Shmiddty Actually in here i thought to use ShortCode for the identify who is the supporter.. who is the university & so..on.When i go to login i checked there.Username,Password & the Shortcode.Can you suggest me a another good solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedures `@LoginID` is the ID for SupporterReg or UniversityReg, not for Login

In Login, your LoginID column should be defined as `int identity(1,1)` and you should specify column names in your insert

```
INSERT INTO Login (column, names, go here)
values(@LoginID,@UserName,@Password,'SUP')
```

Comment: I think that he's using that stored to make sure that have in both tables the same Id, withouth using PK and FK. In that case, this isn't what he needs

Comment: @ElVieejo, I would hope neither he nor you would ever do something like that on purpose. Anytime you design so that you cannot use FKs then your database design is irretrievably flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble is that your procedure is attempting to insert multiple values into the SupporterReg table however you are not including a value for the SupporterID column, which has been defined a NOT NULL.

You can either pass a value along with that insert statement, or adjust the table DDL so that it's an IDENTITY column and will fill that data for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is wrong. You should not be using the id from two different tables in the login table as the loginid. This is a model that can not work in practice as both tables will sooner or later have the same id and you won't know which one the login relates to. You have a the parent child relationship reversed.

The correct  design is to insert to Login first making the loginid the identity. Then insert to the child table of either UniversityReg  or SupporterReg. When you do this you can have FKs and referntial integrity.